# What road tire should I buy for my new cyclocross

Tags: tire, cyclocross, upgrade-or-new-bike

I'm a recreational rider wanting to get more serious with cycling. I like Cyclocross bikes for their versatility and plan on commuting to work using my new entry-level Nashbar CX1. I've heard that knobby tires can be pretty rough on the road so I'm looking for a pair road tires to put on. What size should I consider? Some people use 700 x 30 while others recommend 700 x 32 or 700 x 33. What are the differences between these specs? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Are you just commuting on roads or are you planning to do a little cross or what?

Comment: I'm commuting on paved roads. I'm planning on taking the bike out to the trail nearby on the weekend. Nothing extreme tho.

Comment: I like 700 x 35

Comment: I'm in your same position. In my case, I have 700cx38 on my Cyclocross Norco Sora 2017 for weekend trails and diary commuting.

Comment: You are probably after a gravel bike / tyres, not to be confused with a cyclocross bike/ tyres.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how much your budget is. Usually tires with lower rolling resistance comes a bit, if not alot, more expensive. Sk if you are just going for a pair that's cheap. I think it's best if you go for a 700x30. Since this one has the least amount of tire against the road.

I'm also trying to figure out why you don't want to invest in another set of wheels for commuting? Which in that case would mean you can try a road bike tire. A 25 or 28 road tire wouldn't be bad for a cyclocross bike, and I guess it is also ideal for local urban commute.

Again, it is up to you.

Comment: Once you get outside of knobbies versus smooth tread pattern, rolling resistance is more a function of tire compound and tire carcass construction and tire pressure than tire width and/or contact patch size.

Comment: Thanks Phoenix. Having an extra set of wheels is a great idea. I suppose I never thought of it.

Comment: Sure @Dug. It was great trying to help. 

Comment: Yes @Rider_X but he was asking for cyclocross tires. So I said there are also cyclocross tires with low rolling resistance. Which doesn't come cheap btw.

Comment: @Phoenix the OP asked for "road tires" for a cyclocross bike.